# What is the output of running class test? (Java, abstract classes)

Tags: java, abstract-class

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Circle9();
  }
}

public abstract class GeometricObject {
  protected GeometricObject() {
    System.out.print("A");
  }

  protected GeometricObject(String color, boolean filled) {
    System.out.print("B");
  }
}
public class Circle9 extends GeometricObject {
  /** Default constructor */
  public Circle9() {
    this(1.0);
    System.out.print("C");
  }

  /** Construct circle with a specified radius */
  public Circle9(double radius) {
    this(radius, "white", false);
    System.out.print("D");
  }

  /** Construct a circle with specified radius, filled, and color */
  public Circle9(double radius, String color, boolean filled) {
    super(color, filled);
    System.out.print("E");
  }
}
```

A. ABCD

B. BACD

C. CBAE

D. BEDC

The correct answer is BEDC But I don't see how. Within the constructor of the `Circle9` class, shouldn't there be an implied no-arg call to `super()` meaning there should be an A in front?

Comment: Since you have an explicit call to a super constructor with arguments Java will **not** add a default call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are calling explicit parent constructor with argument, hence implicit call of default `super()` is ignored.

Answer (score 2):

just have a look what you are calling and in which order:

Lets play small game of substitution, 
you are calling `new Circle9();`  which become

```
 this(1.0);
 System.out.print("C");
```

`this(1.0)` is another constructor in class Circle9 so we can replace it by:

```
this(radius, "white", false);
System.out.print("D");
System.out.print("C");
```

`this(radius, "white", false);` same as above, it is another constructor and after we replace this call we have

```
super(color, filled);
System.out.print("E");
System.out.print("D");
System.out.print("C");
```

this `super(color, filled);` is explicit call to superclass constructor, so after we substitute code we have

```
super();
System.out.print("B");
System.out.print("E");
System.out.print("D");
System.out.print("C");
```

`super()` is hidden call to constructor of `Object` class  and print statement generate you output `BEDC`

I hope it was helpful